# MongoDB, MapReduce: Join

Tags: javascript, mongodb, join, mongodb-query, mapreduce

> 

Hi everyone,

I have 2 collections:
countries and regions and need to produce a collection with 2 MapReduce programs, which should together represent a join between attributes of these 2 collecitons.

collection regions has the following attributes:
RegionID
CountryID
RegionName

(for example: RegionID: 1234799sk89, CountryID: 15, RegionName: UpperAustria)

collection countries has the following attributes:
CountryId
CountryName

(for example: CountryId: 15, CountryName: Austria)

I already wrote the MapReduce programs:

```
var mapfunction=function(){emit(this.CountryID, this.Region)}

var reducefunction=function(key,value){return (value)}

db.regions.mapReduce(mapfunction,reducefunction,{query:{CountryID: 15 },out: 'Austria_Regions'}),
{"result" : "Austria_Regions", "ok" : 1 };



var mapfunction1=function(){emit(this.CountryId, this.Country)}

var reducefunction1=function(key,value){return (value)}

db.countries.mapReduce(mapfunction1,reducefunction1,{query:{CountryId: 15 },out: 'Country_Id'}),
{"result" : "Country_Id", "ok" : 1 };
```

> 

Now, I have to make a join between these two new collections.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried `$lookup`?

Comment: @Joe hi joe, 
yes, it tried but I think I do something wrong:


`db.regions.aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
           {
               from:"Country_Id",
               localField: "CountryID",
               foreignField: "CountryId",               
               as : "AustriaRegions"
           } 
}])`